# How to return states of LSTM in MXNet?

Tags: keras, lstm, rnn, mxnet

I used MXNet previously to beat keras+tensorflow accuracy in CNN regression models.
Now I am trying to implement LSTM, which in keras runs fine:

```
from keras.layers import LSTM,Flatten,Input
from keras import Model
import numpy as np

def make_keras_stacked_lstm():
    inp = Input(shape=(100,1))
    lstm1 = LSTM(16, return_sequences=True)(inp)
    lstm2 = LSTM(1, return_sequences=True)(lstm1)
    outp = Flatten()(lstm2)
    return Model([inp], outp)

def keras_main():
    ins = np.random.uniform(size=(1000,100,1))
    outs = np.random.uniform(size=(1000,100))
    model = make_keras_stacked_lstm()
    model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
    model.fit(ins, outs, epochs=1, validation_split=.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main()
    keras_main()
```

How can I translate this to MXNet, in either Symbol or gluon dialect? I found no "return_sequences=True" analogue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best emulation (although I didn't check full equivalency):

```
import mxnet as mx

SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 100

stack = mx.gluon.rnn.SequentialRNNCell()
stack.add(mx.gluon.rnn.LSTMCell(16, prefix='first')
stack.add(mx.gluon.rnn.LSTMCell(1, prefix='first')

x, _ = stack.unroll(length=SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
    inputs=x,
    layout='NTC',
    merge_outputs=True,
)
```

Here `layout='NTC'` is for the case when input shape is (samples, timesteps, channels).